# Ler XML com nós iguais PHP

Tags: php, xml

Tenho o xml exemplo:

```
<Listings>
    <Listing>
        <Title>Nome</Title>
        <Details>
            <Description>
                dados
            </Description>
        </Details>
        <Media>
            <Item medium="image">
                https://site.com.br/PM.jpeg
            </Item>
            <Item medium="image">
                https://site.com.br/PM.jpeg
            </Item>
            <Item medium="image">
                https://site.com.br/PM.jpeg
            </Item>
        </Media>
    </Listing>
        <Listing>
            <Title>Nome</Title>
            <Details>
                <Description>
                    dados
                </Description>
            </Details>
            <Media>
                <Item medium="image">
                    https://site.com.br/PM.jpeg
                </Item>
                <Item medium="image">
                    https://site.com.br/PM.jpeg
                </Item>
                <Item medium="image">
                    https://site.com.br/PM.jpeg
                </Item>
            </Media>
        </Listing>
</Listings>
```

Estou lendo com a função `simplexml_load_file`, a leitura dos dados ocorre normalmente, meu problema é como ler todos os itens dentro do nó `<Media>`
Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
foreach($xml->Listings as $registro):
     echo 'Título: ' . $registro->Listing->Title . '<br>';

            foreach($registro->Listing->Media as $item):
                echo 'Imagem: ' . $item->Item . '<br>';
            endforeach;

endforeach;
```

Comment: Caro, tudo bem que você escolheu uma resposta *"tente isto"*, que não explica nada, é um critério seu de escolha e não posso e nem vou tentar interferir... ainda sim adicionei uma explicação extra sobre o uso de trim para remover os espaços extras desnecessários: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/326045/3635 que pode lhe ser útil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O primeiro elemento (chamado elemento root) é o `<Listings>`, ou seja, o objeto em `$xml` já é o `<Listings>`, então não tem sentido tentar pegar `$xml->Listings`, pois o `$xml` já é ele.

Também falta iterar os `<Items>` dentro do `<Media>`, já que é mais de um, então tem que usar um loop, como `foreach`

O correto seria:

```
$listings = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($listings as $listing):

    echo 'Título: ' . trim($listing->Title) . "<br>";

    foreach($listing->Media as $items):
        foreach($items as $item):
            echo 'Imagem: ' . trim($item) . "<br>";
        endforeach;
    endforeach;

endforeach;
```

Note que o seu xml retorna espaços entre as urls, então com `trim()` você pode eliminar os espaçamentos desnecessários.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite,

Tenta isso aqui:

```
foreach($xml->Listings as $registro):
     echo 'Título: ' . $registro->Listing->Title . '<br>';

            foreach($registro->Listing->Media as $item):
            $loop = count($item);    

            for($i = 0; $i < $loop; $i++){
                    echo 'Imagem: ' . $item->Item[$i] . '<br>';
            }

            endforeach;

endforeach;
```